# No values being output

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm having a problem coding my first Perl program.

What I'm trying to do here is getting the maximum, minimum,total and average of a list of numbers using a subroutine for each value and another subroutine to print the final values. I'm using a "private" for all my variables, but I still couldn't print my values.

Here is my code:

```
&max(<>);

&print_stat(<>);

sub max {

    my ($mymax) = shift @_;

    foreach (@_) {

        if ( $_ > $mymax ) {
            $mymax = $_;
        }
    }

    return $mymax;
}

sub print_stat {

    print max($mymax);
}
```

Comment: In list context, `<>` reads until EOF (returning each line read as a separate string). The second use of `<>` returns nothing since the first already read to the EOF. if you want to pass the values returned by the first use of `<>` to two different subs, you'll need to store them somewhere.

Comment: Tip: Always use `use strict; use warnings 'all';`

Comment: Tip: Never use `&` in front of a sub call (unless it's one of the extremely rare situations where you actually mean to override the sub's prototype).

Comment: Tip: Use a consistent indenting strategy!

Comment: Tip: You'll get fewer surprises if you put your top-level code after your sub definitions. Better yet, also put curlies around your top-level code.

Comment: I'm very much a fan of having the top-level code at the start of the script. Apart from meaning I have to use parentheses around all my function arguments (which I prefer to do anyway) what other surprises am I opening myself up for?

Comment: Have a look at `List::Util` which has `max, min, sum` methods.  Average is just `sum / count`.   http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html

Comment: @GrantMcLean All top-level variables will be implicitly in scope in your functions. This can cause surprising behavior e.g. if you use a variable `$foo` in your function but you forgot to declare it, that's normally an error but silently does the wrong thing if your main code also uses a variable called `$foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list_nums = qw(10 21 30 42 50 63 70);
ma_xi(@list_nums);

sub ma_xi
{
    my @list_ele = @_;
    my $set_val_max = '0'; my $set_val_min = '0';
    my $add_all_vals = '0';
    foreach my $each_ele(@list_ele)
    {
        $set_val_max = $each_ele if($set_val_max < $each_ele);
        $set_val_min = $each_ele if($set_val_min eq '0');
        $set_val_min = $each_ele if($set_val_min > $each_ele);
        $add_all_vals += $each_ele;
    }

    my $set_val_avg = $add_all_vals / scalar(@list_ele) + 1;

    print "MAX: $set_val_max\n";
    print "MIN: $set_val_min\n";
    print "TOT: $add_all_vals\n";
    print "AVG: $set_val_avg\n";

    #Return these values into array and get into the new sub routine's

}
```

Comment: Please comment before voting

Answer (score 0):

Some notes

- Use plenty of whitespace to lay out your code. I have tidied the Perl code in your question so that I could read it more easily, without changing its semantics
- You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write
- *Never* use an ampersand `&` in a subroutine call. That hasn't been necessary or desirable since Perl 4 over twenty-five years ago. Any tutorial that tells you otherwise is wrong
- Using `<>` in a list context (such as the parameters to a subroutine call) will read all of the file and exhaust the file handle. Thereafter, any calls to `<>` will return `undef`
- You should use `chomp` to remove the newline from each line of input
- You declare `$mymax` within the scope of the `max` subroutine, but then try to print it in `print_stat` where it doesn't exists. `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` would have caught that error for you
- Your `max` subroutine returns the maximum value that it calculated, but you never use that return value

Below is a fixed version of your code.

Note that I've read the whole file into array `@values` and then chomped them all at once. In general it's best to read and process input one line at a time, which would be quite possible here but I wanted to say as close to your original code as possible

I've also saved the return value from `max` in variable `$max`, and then passed that to `print_stat`. It doesn't make sense to try to read the file again and pass all of those values to `print_stat`, as your code does

I hope this helps

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @values = <>;
chomp @values;

my $max = max(@values);
print_stat( $max );

sub max {
    my $mymax = shift;

    for ( @_ ) {
        if ( $_ > $mymax ) {
            $mymax = $_;
        }
    }

    return $mymax;
}

sub print_stat {
    my ($val) = @_;

    print $val, "\n";
}
```

---

#### Update

Here's a version that calculates all of the statistics that you mentioned. I don't think subroutines are a help in this case as the solution is short and no code is reusable

Note that I've added the data at the end of the program file, after `__DATA__`, which lets me read it from the `DATA` file handle. This is often handy for testing

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($n, $max, $min, $tot);

while ( <DATA> ) {

    next unless /\S/; # Skip blank lines

    chomp;

    if ( not defined $n ) {
        $max = $min = $tot = $_;
    }
    else {
        $max = $_ if $max < $_;
        $min = $_ if $min > $_;
        $tot += $_;
    }

    ++$n;
}

my $avg = $tot / $n;

printf "\$n   = %d\n",   $n;
printf "\$max = %d\n",   $max;
printf "\$min = %d\n",   $min;
printf "\$tot = %d\n",   $tot;
printf "\$avg = %.2f\n", $avg;


__DATA__
7
6
1
5
1
3
8
7
```

#### output

```
$n   = 8
$max = 8
$min = 1
$tot = 38
$avg = 4.75
```

Comment: That's what made me more confused, because I was required to have sub routine for each value I'm looking for. I have learned a lot from all the answer thank you all so much for your help.